# set auto_increment value to old table items

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have in one table two fields (title, content) and i inserted some values...:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| title                                | content                  |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| hello word                           | this is my first content |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| smoke Smoking is bad for your health | But i love it            |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

if I add a auto_increment field called ID, the previously input values ​​take ID = 0:

```
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|ID | title                                | content                  |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 0 | hello word                           | this is my first content |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 0 | smoke Smoking is bad for your health | But i love it            |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

and i need this:

```
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|ID | title                                | content                  |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1 | hello word                           | this is my first content |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2 | smoke Smoking is bad for your health | But i love it            |
+---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

The only way to set correct ID to old values is php+foreach? or i forgot something to do with sql/mysql to takes faster and automatically the correct ID values?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using something like phpMyAdmin to add this field ID with auto_increment? Or how are you adding this field?

Comment: @dbf i tried with 2 ways(phpmyadmin and code). My code:
ALTER TABLE  `blog` ADD  `id` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,now its my time to help you :P.

You puts SQL code in a php page or in phpmyadmin online code editor? Sometimes phpmyadmin online editor fails, try it in your php page and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD ID INT IDENTITY
```

Comment: Does that make it a PRIMARY KEY automatically? :)

Comment: To make it a primary key, I would use
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(ID)

I hope this helps !